# What is the difference between ContentDetails.RegionRestriction and ContentDetails.CountryRestriction in the Youtube API V3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Below I have my simple request that retrieves `contentDetails` for a specific video.

```
        var youTubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "your-apikey",
            ApplicationName = "DIGITAL.CLI"
        });
        var channelsListRequest = new VideosResource.ListRequest(youTubeService, "contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.Id = "FakBv-xNTeU";
        var response = channelsListRequest.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
```

In the response I get a list of regions where the video is blocked, but there is also a section that isn't in the response called `countryRestrictions`.

```
{
"etag": "8Dlzw_juiiGAkJUxdgfegatGe34",
"items": [
  {
    "contentDetails": {
      "caption": "false",
      "contentRating": {},
      "definition": "hd",
      "dimension": "2d",
      "duration": "PT1M37S",
      "licensedContent": true,
      "projection": "rectangular",
      "regionRestriction": {
        "blocked": [
          "US",
          "FM",
          "MP",
          "VI",
          "GU",
          "MH",
          "PR",
          "PW",
          "AS",
          "UM"
        ]
      }
    },
    "etag": "-DZJdN2PuXnNfuceW0s7RVa4Y9I",
    "id": "FakBv-xNTeU",
    "kind": "youtube#video"
  }
],
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"pageInfo": {
  "resultsPerPage": 1,
  "totalResults": 1
}}
```

So this video has `regionRestrictions`, but no country restrictions. Is `countryRestrictions` still in use? The client library documentation of [`VideoConntentDetails`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/VideoContentDetails.html) has the same description for both of them.

And as a bonus question, if the `allowed` list contains items, then does that mean that all countries not in the allowed list are blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the client library documentation of [`VideoContentDetailsRegionRestriction`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/VideoContentDetailsRegionRestriction.html), this model class is deprecated; thus the *client library property* `regionRestriction` is deprecated too.

The client library is mapping its property `countryRestriction` from the YouTube Data API's property [`contentDetails.regionRestriction`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction).

According to the official specification of the YouTube Data API's [`Videos resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource), there's no property `countryRestriction` that this kind of API resource contains.

---

The answer to your second question is: yes, all countries not in the allowed list are blocked (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**`contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed[]`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction.allowed%5B%5D) (list)
> A list of region codes that identify countries where the video is viewable. *If this property is present and a country is not listed in its value, then the video is blocked from appearing in that country.* If this property is present and contains an empty list, the video is blocked in all countries.